# How to get all the td values of a Table in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable in which i am showing child rows expand collapse functionality.It is working well but i want to get the contents of last td of a table.For now i have create a function which is placing some hard coded value in the datatable expanded place . In that place i want to get those td values. !

[image]

Here is the code i am posting

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/css/dataTables.responsive.css">


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
td.details-control {
background:     url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat     center center;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
tr.shown td.details-control {
background:   url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat    center center;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
  /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
   function format ( d ) {

    var v;

        $("#example tbody tr").each(function() {

        // Within tr we find the last td child element and get content
        v = $(this).find("td:last-child").html();
        return v;
        });

    // Within tr we find the last td child element and get content
    //alert($(this).find("td:last-child").html());


    return '<fieldset> <legend>     </legend>   <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+ 
    '<td>'+v+'</td>'
   '</tr>'

    '</table> </fieldset>' 


  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody ').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
}
else {
    // Open this row
    console.log(row);
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
   }
  } );
  // End add event 

 $("#divPopUp").dialog({
    resizable: true,
   autoOpen: false,
   width: 550,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
    "Save": function() {
        var text = $(this).find( ":checkbox:checked" ).map(function() {
            return this.value+' ';
        }).get().join();

        var obj = $(this).data("opener");
        $(obj).parents('td:first').siblings(':eq(2)').find(':text').val(text);
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
close:function(){
    $(this).find( ":checkbox" ).removeAttr('checked');
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
});

$('button.btn').on('click', function(){
var title = $(this).parents('td:first').siblings(':eq(0)').text();
console.log("title is : "  + title);
$( "#divPopUp" ).data('opener', this).dialog( "option", "title", title    ).dialog( "open" );
      var text =          $(this).parents('td:first').siblings(':eq(2)').find(':input').val();
if($.trim(text) != ''){
      var texts = text.split(" ,"); 
    $.each(texts, function(i, value){    $("#divPopUp").find(':checkbox[value="'+$.trim(value)+'"]').prop('checked', true);
       });
     }
   });
 } );
   </script>
   <body>
     <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
             <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
           <th>Age</th>
           <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class="details-control" ></td>       
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>


    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="details-control" ></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>


    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="details-control" ></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>    
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Inside that format function i want to get all td values of datatables.Somebody please help

Comment: by last td you mean the last column or the last cell?

Comment: I would guess the last cell of each row right?

Comment: yes it is.....I want each last td

Comment: I am getting only the last child value in each expansion of the the Green Plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it in jQuery, as you have your last `td` of each row as nothing I deleted them to show it works using the salary column.

This gets the value of each row's last `td`, in the function you can do whatever you want to the values.

```js
// Run function for each tbody tr
$("#example tbody tr").each(function() {

  // Within tr we find the last td child element and get content
  alert($(this).find("td:last-child").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="details-control"></td>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to return with this function format ( d ) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return '<fieldset> <legend>    Agencies  </legend>   <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>agencies has to come from data attributes from tds</td>'
       '</tr>'

    '</table> </fieldset>'

Comment: @lucifer What you just said made no sense. Posting code in the comment isn't helping either. Post all relevant code into your question .

Comment: your code helped but i am still not able to implement my functinality.I want to get the last column value in each expansion of the Plus sign. I am posting back my question

Comment: will you see my uppdates post

Comment: @lucifer So you want to grab the last `td` (salary) and display that number in the expanded bit?

Comment: @lucifer As you already had code there for it I just changed it little. You was already getting `row.data` using this you can easily get the value you want. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ntsbpkb/). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @lucifer No problem :) You was very close to doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with jquery.

Code:

```
$('#example tr td:last-child').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Try this code hopefully this code work's for you.

Comment: but i have to show each last child value in each click of the plus sign in the   function (d) how to do that/

Comment: @lucifer I think you have a demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8ntsbpkb/) as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Gets the collection of matched elements: last <td> in all rows:

```
var last_col = $("#example tbody tr td:last-child");
```

Now you can get the <td> values as an array of numbers ([jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) or [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
var values = $.map(last_col.get(), function (td) {
    return +$(td).text().replace(/[\$\,\s]/g, "") || 0;
});
```

Bonus: If you want sum (or operate) each values in the array (from left-to-right), you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var total = values.reduce(function (prev, current) { 
    return prev + current;
}, 0 /*starts prev*/);
```

You can run this code here: **https://jsfiddle.net/4kw6yco7/**

Answer (score 0):

Say You want a whole data of a row then

```
var row = '<tr>' + '<td id="tduid">' + value['uid'] + '</td>' + '<td>' + value['name'] + '</td>' + '<td>' + value['address'] + '</td>' + '<td>' + tags + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<button class="deleteUser btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="del">Edit</button>' + '</td></tr>';
```

You need the values of this row. So next,

```
$('#del').click(function(e) {                                                       
     var tuid = $(this).closest('tr').find('#tduid').text();
                alert(tuid);
      });
```