# jQuery executes before page finishes loading even though I'm using $(window).on('load', function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scrape some times from https://www.speedrun.com/mm for a chrome extension but the issue I'm having is that jQuery loads before the webpage has completed loading. When I refresh the page while having Inspect open it works just fine (I'm assuming it's making the webpage take longer to load) but otherwise I can't scrape the data, it will return blank. Is there any way for me to ensure that the data is ALWAYS loaded first?

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var worldRecord = $('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
    alert(worldRecord);
});
```

Edit: I tried this as well and got the same result

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var worldRecord = $('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
  alert(worldRecord);
});
```

Comment: put your code inside document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround since loading after the ajax completes doesn't seem to be working. I used the setTimeout function and set it to one second to see if that worked and it did :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var worldRecord = $('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
        alert(worldRecord);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this edited with $(document).ready

Load is called when all assets are done loading, including images.But the ready is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var worldRecord = $('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
  alert(worldRecord);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is what I had originally tried before I switched it to window. I'm not sure why neither of these are working :L

Comment: I have edited the answer with more information might help you

Comment: Unfortunately the website is huge that it would not be realistic to post the whole code. If you click the link to the website and inspect (F12) the website you can look at the HTML though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959416/how-to-get-all-the-td-values-of-a-table-in-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside `document.ready` .

```
$(function() {
   var worldRecord = $('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
   alert(worldRecord);
});
```

Comment: I get the same result when I use document.ready. Is there any other way to make it load later?

Answer (score 0):

The leaderboard data seems to be loaded using ajax. Have you tried using .ajaxSuccess() or .ajaxComplete() instead of .ready?

Comment: I have tried using .ajaxComplete() based on the documentation http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ and now the alert will not pop up at all. Do you think it is infinitely loading the ajax, so it never loads the alert?

Comment: I can see an ajaxSuccess event firing. Have you tested that as well?

Comment: I tried ajaxSuccess as well and it didn't work. The only solution I've found is setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Please check once if you are getting $ as undefined, 
Use different instance of JQUERY like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var worldRecord = jQuery('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text();
  alert(worldRecord);
});
```

Comment: I just attempted this and it is the same result as when I use $ unfortunately.

Comment: It seems like there is some method which is not finishing loading actually. for debuggnig, once try plain `alert('abc');` on document ready Not using `jQuery('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text(); alert(worldRecord); ` if again its not doing alert then it shoud be browser problem, try different browser.

Comment: It is giving an alert but the alert is blank because it is loading before the table loads on the page.

Comment: I suppose the `jQuery('.nobr.center.hidden-xs').text(); ` has some data tables that is using ajax or similar source to load and hence data is loading late. In that case, you try to get that status if `div` is not empty, only then use `alert(worldRecord);`